# RGB color of pixel

Tags: java, android

I wanna make the same(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_yuanryan_chen.BT_LED) app. I want to get a color of some pixel like here(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixz84.png). How can I get the color(rgb)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it from scratch since there is a set of readily-made libraries for colour picking, for example, this library:

https://github.com/jbruchanov/AndroidColorPicker

for more libraries you can check this: 
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/18?sort=created